# LWC lightning-input-field Remains Disabled when Rerendered Using Another field-name

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

**Problem:**

A dynamic lightning-input-field remains "disabled" after having been a formula field, even if it is no longer pointing at a disabled field. It's possible to workaround this by hiding the component with some if:true value, then showing it again, but I'm unable to do this in one move (it has to be clicked on and off again). Is there a known workaround?

**Markup:**

*example.html*

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name={objectApiName}>
        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field
                field-name={fieldApiName}
                variant="label-stacked"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button
                variant="brand"
                type="submit"
                name="save"
                label="Save"></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

*example.js*

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class DynamicInputField extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    @api fieldApiName;
}
```

**Example:**

A GUI allows users to click on a field and bring up the dynamic input field to edit its value. If the first field clicked on is an editable text field, the form appears as editable and can be submitted. If the second field is a formula field, the current value of the formula field is displayed in the input, but it cannot be interacted with. If the third field is another editable field, it remains disabled such that it cannot be interacted with (even if this is the original field!).

Comment: I remember looking in to a similar issue previously, and I found that the code doesn't fully support dynamic field changes like this. You might need to write your own.